# Adding invitation to Drupal for future registations

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

I would like to implement a simple invitation system on the landing page for new users.

Specifically a form where users can just leave only their e-mail address to register for future potential invite (without creating a full account at this point). And then, when necessary to allow me to see the list of people interested to receive such invite to send them an activation link, at which point they can use that link to create a full account and get access to the rest of the website.

I tried to figure out if I can implement such a system with pure Drupal but I don't think I can.

Can anyone help me figure out how to solve this problem or a specific plugin that does that?

*Just to clarify, I'm not talking about group of even invitations or invitations from other users. Specifically website registration invitation as described above.*

Comment: You need custom development , pay your attention on fact it's a good client for bots flooding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about using Simplenews module?

It allows you to create multiple newsletters, you would create one for each of the future events or just one for all events. Website visitors can then subscribe to the newsletter and Simplenews already provides an out-of-the-box Double Opt-in procedure to prevent bots flooding the list.

Once the event is going to be open for registration, you can create an issue of the newsletter (including a link to yourdomain.com/user/register) and send it to all subscribers.

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly an elegant solution, but it sounds like it would do the trick for me. Thank you! :)